# Question about writing TS code with interfaces etc

Tags: typescript

I am new to TS and I have couple of questions.
Since TypeScript introduced unions types, I wonder if there is any reason to declare an enum type, can I only use types instead and forget about enums?

```js
enum Status {
  Admin = "Admin",
  User = "User",
  Moderator = "Moderator",
}
```

or

```js
type Status = "Admin" | "User" | "Moderator"
```

Also as for interfaces and types, aswell I heard they both work the same and I should use one of them only, is that true I can do this and do everything with interfaces?

e.g

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  ...
}

let person: Person = { my obj }
```

or

```
type Person = {
 name: string;
}

let person: Person = { 
  my obj
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Both of these are (primarily) opinion-based, so they're off-topic here.

Comment: Enum is different than interface or type with union. Enum is more powerful and has many different use cases. Enum preserve the type and value and interface or types, only describe what type of data it would be.

Comment: I don't think it's recommended to use an enum as a string union type. It's just not intended for that use

Comment: TS has (string) literal types, enums are not "safer" than string literals.